# scandir returns dirs but not fileq

Tags: php, scandir

I'm using scandir to locate the a folder and then check inside for the file I want to use in a link. The where I'm using it to grab the folder is fine but if I try to get the file it comes back null.

```
$path = "/path/to/plugin";
$dir = array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.'));
$tmpYear = 0;
$tmpMonth = 0;
foreach($dir as $year){
  if((int)$year > $tmpYear){
    $tmpYear = (int)$year;
  }
}
$path2 = $path."/".$tmpYear;
$dir2 = array_diff(scandir($path2), array('..', '.'));
foreach ($dir2 as $month) {
  if((int)$month > $tmpMonth){
    $tmpMonth = (int)$month;
  }
}
$comPath = $path2."/".$tmpMonth;
$dir3 = scandir($comPath);
foreach ($dir3 as $filename) {
    $finalfile = $filename;
}
var_dump($dir3);
```

That will dump a NULL but like if I var_dump($dir2) which is just up one level I'll get the folder name correctly.

Edit: The entire file/folder structure is owned by www-data:www-data my server is ubuntu running a LEMP stack. The permissions have been set to 766 for everything aswell.

Comment: what is the directory structure? are there folders like `2015,2016,2017` with subfolders `1,2,3,4...`??

Comment: Yes essentialy. It's YY/MM/ folders and then in each month folder theres a pdf that I want to get its name and then generate a link for it.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the use of some of the `Recursive Iterator` classes I used the following code to create a directory structure with dummy files.

```
function createpath( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
    if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
        createpath( dirname( $path ) );
        mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
        clearstatcache();
    }
}


foreach( range( 2000, 2018 ) as $yr ){
    for( $i=1; $i < 13; $i++ ){
        $path=$dir . $yr . '/' . $i;
        createpath( $path );
        file_put_contents( $path .'/pseudo_pdf_file__'.$i.'.pdf.txt', 'Hello World '.$i );
    }
}
```

Which gave a directory structure like this: ( cmd line )

```
c:\Temp\fileuploads\1>dir /B
2000
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
```

And then within each a sub-directory structure like this: ( cmd line )

```
c:\Temp\fileuploads\1\2018>dir /B /OD
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

With each of these folders containing a pseudo pdf file as named above.

---

And, hopefully I did not misunderstand, the following uses a [`recursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) in conjunction with a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to work through all folders from a given starting point - using the `isFile` method to test for files rather than directories.

```
/* all files found will be added to this array */
$files=array();

$pttn='@(\.pdf)@';

/* the start directory for the search */
$dir='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';

/* create the directory iterator */
$dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );

/* use a recursive iterator to iterate through directories */
foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $obj => $info ) {
    /* As it is files you wish to find, use `isFile()` method */
    if( $info->isFile() ){

        /* Match file name against basic patter to test for .pdf files */
        preg_match( $pttn, $info->getFileName(), $col );

        /* Add matching files to the output array */
        if( !empty( $col ) ){
            $files[]=str_replace( realpath( $dir ),'', realpath( $info->getPathName() ) );
        }
    }
}
/* If any files were found, process the output array */
if( !empty( $files ) ){
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        /* do stuff with $file */
        echo $file;
    }
}
```

From this point the generation of links should be straightforward - hope this helps.

Comment: This is a lot better way to go about things I think I will try to rewrite it to use those recursive iterators. Also it turned out the reason my code didn't work was the file name was '01' for the month and I was typecasting it to int which shaved off the 0.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was casting month as int and that removed the leading 0 in the folder name.